# How to extract data from Parcelable Object in Android

Tags: android, parcelable

I'm getting some hash code instead of real object in below code what could have been wrong.

```
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        posters = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_FOR);

        Toast.makeText(this,posters.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(posters,this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: What data type is `posters`? If it is ArrayList, than you need to read items in a loop.

Comment: @Gotiasits Thank you, got it.

Comment: @Gotiastis, this is not true. If an arraylist was put in a bundle, then there is no need to make a loop to retrieve all the items. `getParcelableArrayList` is especially made for that purpose

Comment: @ArthurAttout no that is error in my code.

Comment: @ArthurAttout Take a look at [officiall android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String)) return value is in fact an ArrayList

Comment: Yes it is. And this is why you don't have to "read items in a loop" since it's already an ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String)) return value of method `getParcelableArrayList (String key)` is ArrayList.

In order to access items of this array, you need to loop through this list to get individual items.